# rails activeresource messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I have a quick question about active resource.  If I have a User resource, when I do a call like

```
User.find(1).put(:promote, :position => 'manager')
```

According to the api it translates into this call /users/1/promote.xml?position=manager

My question is this.  Is activeresource actually making two calls here?  find doing a get, then putting on that object, or does appending .put to the .find mean that it just makes a single call.  If this is so, then the only reason for the .find is the give the proper url format of /users/:id/promote ??

I couldn't find in the docs where this might be specified, but it's the .find that makes me think maybe two service calls are taking place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ActiveResource works like ActiveRecord, I would say 'yes'. If you do something like

```
Foo.find(1).update_attributes(:name=>"Bar")
```

ActiveRecord first does a select to get the object and then issues an update call to the database to change the record. I would presume that ActiveResources functions in a similar manner where it issues two web services calls to get the object and then update the object.

Comment: I'm hoping this isn't the case, that would seem incredibly poor from a service performance standpoint.  Since it's all xml messages, the initial find does nothing for me, except that just calling User.put(:promote...) doesn't return a user object, but rather a hash of user attributes...  so the api recommends using User.find(x).put...   I'm still interested though so know if anyone has a definitive answer

Comment: You could run a packet sniffer, e.g. WireShark, to test this definitively.

Comment: The thing of it is, Rails needs to verify that User.find(1) actually exists and doesn't return nil, otherwise it's trying to perform a put operation on a non-existent record. This leads me to believe that it does two calls, but I agree with @Schrockwell, packet sniffer FTW

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your intializers:

```
class ActiveResource::Connection
  #   Creates new Net::HTTP instance for communication with
  #   remote service and resources.
  def http
    http = Net::HTTP.new(@site.host, @site.port)
    http.use_ssl = @site.is_a?(URI::HTTPS)
    http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE if http.use_ssl
    http.read_timeout = @timeout if @timeout
    #Here's the addition that allows you to see the output
    http.set_debug_output $stderr
    return http
  end
end
```

Search '"http.set_debug_output $stderr" "ActiveResource"' to find the original author of this helpful tip.